# JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes when applying function with json in it

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to make a function to prepare the `dataframes` that I have. This is the function

```
def prepare_data(x):
    parsed_df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in x])
    // other further processes
    return parsed_df
```

But when I'm testing it with one of my `dataframes`, it raised error

```
data_id99 = data_id99['json_col'].apply(prepare_data)

Output : JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

It works perfectly fine if I do it this way (one single line without using it inside a function)

```
test = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in data_id99['json_col']])
```

But when I turned it into a function it raised error, I don't know what I did wrong because I think I have correctly apply it to the column of the `dataframe` and the function is already in correct way. How to fix this?

Comment: How is your json being created?

Comment: it comes from an uploaded csv, transformed into json then passed to the database

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with the transforming into json process...

Comment: but if it's wrong, should the line `test = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in data_id99['json_col']])` not work too? that line works just fine (single line code, not within function) and returns the result like how I want it. The problem is I need to be able to use it with a function because I have many `dataframes` *sob*

Comment: nevermind, I already find another way to achieve what I want with a loop, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe  your Json file may be mis formatted. Print the json to console and check its integrity in a site such as:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://jsonchecker.com/&ved=2ahUKEwi3u8KV6M3wAhVUC2MBHZFZBuQQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw16qBGfRNySRFHOH-uyTIq3

Typically this error occurs when your Json file has single quotes `'property':` rather than double quotes `"property" :`.

Note that the Json standard explicitly requires the latter.

Comment: but my json is double quoted `{"NO":"1","NIM":"4313010001","NAME":......` I have checked it from that link and my json column indeed contains json values